# Dynamic/Modular Input Component in ReactJS

Tags: forms, input, reactjs

I am just starting with React and I haven't found a usable solution to my problem. I have stumbled up this video [about Redux Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6C22gwvOzaw) but it did not work in my case.

I want to have a dynamic "input" field for my form, meaning I have one component where I specify if its an input or textarea primarily (don't need the rest for this project)

This is my DashFormInput.js which is supposed to be the single "input" field but I'd like it to be dynamic as in being able to change the html element it outputs as well as the props.

```
var DashFormInput = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        value: '',
        actionType: '',
        placeholder: '',
        name: '',
        type: ''
    }
},
handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <input
            actionType={this.props.actionType}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            name={this.props.name}
        />
    );
}
});
```

This is my DashboardForm.js which is the parent component where i want to call my DashFormInput components.

```
var DashboardForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submitted");
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            id="dashboardForm" className="half-section">

            <DashFormInput
                type={'text'}
                name={'address'}
                placeholder={'address'}
                className={'dashInput subsection'} />
        </form>
    )
}
});
```

I am looking for a simple solution, dont need anything too fancy, but if this is just not possible with the standard React Ecosystem I will do it the old-fashioned way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your **DashFormInput.js** render method like

```
render: function() {
    if(this.props.type=="text"){
        return (
            <input
                actionType={this.props.actionType}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                name={this.props.name}
            />
        );
    }
    if(this.props.type=="textarea"){
        return (
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50"
                actionType={this.props.actionType}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                name={this.props.name}
            ></textarea>
        );
    }else{
        return <div>No input type defined</div>;
    }
}
```

Now from **DashboardForm.js** you can change **DashFormInput** component's type prop to "text" or "textarea" and accordingly you will have input box or textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is by utilizing create element (i used a ES2015 style),

```
class DashFormInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state =  {
      value: '',
      actionType: '',
      placeholder: '',
      name: '',
      type: ''
    };
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement(this.props.elementType,
        {
          type: this.props.type,
          name: this.props.name, 
          placeholder:this.props.placeholder, 
          className: this.props.className,
          onChange: this.handleChange
        }
      )
    );
  }
}

class DashboardForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submitted");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} 
        id="dashboardForm" className="half-section">
        <DashFormInput
          elementType = {'textarea'}
          type={'text'}
          name={'address'}
          placeholder={'address'}
          className={'dashInput subsection'} />
      </form>
    );
  }
};

React.render(
  <DashboardForm />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```